# Nuxt3 Socket Closing Unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, websocket, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am trying to create a chat app and I'm in the early stages. I'd like to do this with WebSockets and I implemented it with Nuxt3.

I've succesfully managed to create a plugin and middleware that establishes the connection.
Unfortunately the server(node.js) unexpectedly closes the connection.

I hat hit a brick wall on debugging and I ask connoisseurs for help on that.

`**Script to handle connection from the client - in default.vue**`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const {data: user} = useFetch('/api/user')

function initialiseSocket(user: string) {
  const {$socket, $message:message} = useNuxtApp()

  $socket.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
    console.log(event.data)
  }

  $socket.onopen = () => {
    $socket.send(JSON.stringify(
      {
        type: 'debug',
        user_id: user,
        message_from: null,
        message_to: null,
        message_body: null
      } as typeof message
    ))
  }

  $socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log('Socket closed')
  }

  $socket.onerror = () => {
    console.log('Socket error')
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  if (user.value) {
    if (user.value.body) {
      if (user.value.statusCode === 200) {
        // @ts-ignore
        console.log("User retrieved successfully: " + user.value.body.user_id)
        // @ts-ignore
        initialiseSocket(user.value.body.user_id)
      } else {
        console.log("Received non-200 status code from server when trying to retrieve user " + user.value.statusCode + " " + user.value.body)
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Received empty response from server when trying to retrieve user")
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Unknown internal server error occurred when trying to retrieve user, no user response")
  }
})

</script>
```

`**Middleware to create socket - socket.ts**`

```
import {Message, Client} from "~/ExtraTypes";



// Declare the global WebSocket server
declare global {
    var wss: WebSocketServer;
    var clients: Client[];
}

// Define the WebSocket server and clients array
let wss: WebSocketServer;
let clients: Client[] = [];

// Define the function to handle incoming events
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    if (!global.wss) {
        // Create a new WebSocket server if one doesn't already exist
        // @ts-ignore
        wss = new WebSocketServer({server: event.node.res.socket?.server});

        // Listen for new connections
        wss.on("connection", async (socket) => {
            // Get the user ID from the client's cookies (if available)
            const user_id = getCookie(event, "user") || null;

            // if there is a user id and client is not already connected
            if (user_id && !clients.find((c) => c.user_id === user_id)) {
                // Create a new client object and add it to the clients array
                const client: Client = {
                    user_id,
                    socket,
                    readyState: socket.readyState,
                };
                clients.push(client);

                socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: {
                        user_id,
                        message: "Connected",
                    },
                }));

                // Listen for incoming messages
                socket.on("message", (message) => {
                    // When a message is received, parse it, determine the kind of message, if it's user to user, send it to the appropriate client(s)
                    // otherwise, log it to the console
                    parseMessage(message.toString(), client);
                });


                // Listen for the socket to close
                socket.on("close", () => {
                    // Remove the client from the clients array when the socket is closed
                    clients = clients.filter((c) => c !== client);
                });

                socket.on("error", (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })

            } else {
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    body: {error: "Unauthorized"},
                }));
                console.log("Unauthorized");
            }

            socket.on("close", () => {
                console.log("Socket closed - " + user_id);
            })

            socket.on("error", (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        });
        global.wss = wss;
    }
});

function parseMessage(message: string, sender: Client) {
    let parsedMessage: Message;
    try {
        parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (error) {
        const response = JSON.stringify({
            statusCode: 400,
            body: {error: "Invalid message format"},
        });
        sender.socket.send(response);
        return;
    }

    if (parsedMessage.type == "chat"){
        const {user_id, message_to, message_body} = parsedMessage;
        const recipients = clients.filter((c) => c.user_id === message_to);

        if (!recipients.length) {
            const response = JSON.stringify({
                statusCode: 400,
                body: {error: "User not found"},
            });
            sender.socket.send(response);
            return;
        }

        recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
            if (recipient.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                const response = JSON.stringify({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: {user_id, message_body},
                });
                recipient.socket.send(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(parsedMessage);
    }
}
```

`**Script plugin to establish websocket connection from client - websocket.client.ts**`

```
let socket: WebSocket
let message: Message

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    if (process.server) return

    const wsProtocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:"
    socket = new WebSocket(`${wsProtocol}//${window.location.host}`)

    return {
        provide: {
            socket,
            message
        },
    }
})
```

I speculate maybe js's garbage collection? Or sth beyond my understanding.

The full project is here https://github.com/kgarchie/NuxtTicketerDocker on the `olive` branch

Comment: I found that I needed to set up the server web socket with a different port.

i.e wss = new WebSocketServer({port: websocketPort, host: "localhost"}); instead of  new WebSocketServer({server: event.node.res.socket?.server});

This isn't the intended way I wanted. Because the app will not run on servers that don't support multiple ports, hence the {server: event.node.res.socket?.server} option when initialising the wss

I do not understand why it is not working as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my savior came in the form of uWebSocketJS, which works great. The socket is stable and fast. It offers other features as well, I can't recommend it enough.

Check out the repo https://github.com/kgarchie/NuxtTicketerDocker.git

Edit: The bundle size from this library is huge. I later found out that for nuxt3, the socket will work fine when running the project in build mode.